# How to use robocopy to copy folder/file security + permissions

Tags: scripting, acl, robocopy

I recently copied a bunch of data to a new machine but forgot to enforce ACL permissions. I would like to copy the file/folder security permissions to the destination using **robocopy**. Here is what I have so far

robocopy C:\Users\Dallas\Desktop\source C:\Users\Dallas\Desktop\destination /sec /secfix /xf "*.*"

This copies the users over but NOT the permissions. Any ideas?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: did you tried used ***/COPYALL = copies everything: data, attributes, timestamps, security, ownership and auditing information; overkill really since I specified /SEC*** ?